# Run a command when directory content changes

Tags: java, windows, maven, terminal

Does anyone know how to run a command in terminal whenever changes are detected in a directory? I'm using rb-inotify if that helps.

I want to run `mvn clean package` whenever a certain directory's content changes. I have looked at other questions/answers on here, but nothing seems to work for me.

Comment: Create a `WatchService` that watches a directory and spawn a new process with `ProcessBuilder` when you detect something.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, how would I go about this? I found Oracle's article for creating a `WathcService`, but the demo file they provided was way more than I needed. I really have no idea how to start anything Java related (my startup just changed the backend from Django over the weekend).

Comment: That's a little broad to go over here. You'll have to learn your Java basics. Then follow a tutorial (official or otherwise) on `WatchService` and `ProcessBuilder`.